# InputGroupAddon tag not working with reactstrap. Any possible solution for this

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend

ERROR in ./src/components/TodoForm.js 25:39-54
export 'InputGroupAddon' (imported as 'InputGroupAddon') was not found in 'reactstrap' (possible exports: Accordion, AccordionBody, AccordionContext, AccordionHeader, AccordionItem, Alert, Badge, Breadcrumb, BreadcrumbItem, Button, ButtonDropdown, ButtonGroup, ButtonToggle, ButtonToolbar, Card, CardBody, CardColumns, CardDeck, CardFooter, CardGroup, CardHeader, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardLink, CardSubtitle, CardText, CardTitle, Carousel, CarouselCaption, CarouselControl, CarouselIndicators, CarouselItem, Col, Collapse, Container, Dropdown, DropdownContext, DropdownItem, DropdownMenu, DropdownToggle, Fade, Form, FormFeedback, FormGroup, FormText, Input, InputGroup, InputGroupText, Label, List, ListGroup, ListGroupItem, ListGroupItemHeading, ListGroupItemText, ListInlineItem, Media, Modal, ModalBody, ModalFooter, ModalHeader, Nav, NavItem, NavLink, Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarText, NavbarToggler, Offcanvas, OffcanvasBody, OffcanvasHeader, Pagination, PaginationItem, PaginationLink, Placeholder, PlaceholderButton, Polyfill, Popover, PopoverBody, PopoverHeader, PopperContent, PopperTargetHelper, Progress, Row, Spinner, TabContent, TabPane, Table, Toast, ToastBody, ToastHeader, Tooltip, UncontrolledAccordion, UncontrolledAlert, UncontrolledButtonDropdown, UncontrolledCarousel, UncontrolledCollapse, UncontrolledDropdown, UncontrolledPopover, UncontrolledTooltip, Util)

webpack compiled with 1 error and 2 warnings

Comment: <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                    <Button
                        color="warning"
                        //Todo: OnClick
                    >
                        Add
                    </Button>
</InputGroupAddon>

Answer (score 2):

The Latest version of **reactstrap** doesn't support the use of `InputGroupAddon`. Use it directly from bootstrap.

This should work for you.

```js
<div className="input-group-append">
  <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">Search</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

need to see what you import. I hope this line will help you.

```
import { InputGroup, InputGroupAddon, InputGroupText, Input } from 'reactstrap';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have imported like this only but still it is not working. Please see below implementation for InputGroupAddon                                             
<InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                        <Button
                            color="success"
                        >
                            Add Todo
                        </Button>
                    </InputGroupAddon>

Comment: Is it due to reactstrap version?

Answer (score 1):

I also face a similar issue but I have found an answer at https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/2171.

> InputGroupAddon - This is no longer needed in Bootstrap 5, you can now
> add Buttons, Inputs directly to InputGroups in the order you wish.